# How can I have a search box where people can search for pages within my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a button on my website that when clicked prompts a box allowing users to enter in a term such as "example100" and then it will redirect the user to "mywebsite.com/example100.html but this is done using JS password function and I'm not sure this is best practice. I would much prefer a search box where users could enter in directly from home page (i.e no button)

Additional Notes:
It is likely that I will have 100+ pages and thus I am not sure what best practice is to achieve this.

I Have attached the JS that I currently use via a button below.

All help appreciated!

```
function passWord(){
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Enter Store Code Here','');
    while (testV < 3) {
        if (!pass1)
            history.go(0);
        if (pass1.toUpperCase() == "ExampleStore") {
            alert('You are being redirected!');
            window.open('/examplestore.html');
            break;
        }
        else if (pass1.toUpperCase() == "ExampleStore2") {
            window.open('/examplestore2.html');
            break;
        }

        testV+=1;
        var pass1 = 
            prompt('Store Code Not Recognised, Please Try Again.','Enter Store Code...');
    }

    if (pass1.toLowerCase() != "password" & testV ==3)
        history.go(0);
        return " ";

}
```

Comment: Google how to create search boxes, see using css frameworks like materialize or bootstrap

Comment: you have declared the same thing twice `var pass1`

Comment: There are also braces `{` that are not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help a bit. Instead of using `window.open` try `location`.

I can do this:

```
window.location = pass1 + ".aspx";
```

Or go to an html page in another directory:

```
window.location = "html/" + pass1 + ".html";
```

I have not had to specify anything other than the page (and optional directory). If necessary, try building the url:

```
window.location = 'http://' + pass1 + '.html';
```

A couple other things:

- you have `if (pass1.toUpperCase() == "ExampleStore")`. You're converting pass1 to upper case but testing it against something that is not upper case so it will always fail.
- as mentioned in a comment, you have declared `var pass1 =` twice. the second time (near the end) just use `pass1`.
- the final `if` statement needs braces.

It might also make a difference if you are using a `<button>` or `<input type="button"`>. Try both.

hth.